# Clean up file from git merge

Tags: git, unix, git-merge

Through stupidity, the only version of a big file is from trying to merge, i.e. it contains lots of lines like

```
<<<<<<< HEAD        double[] p1 = ...
                    double[] p2 = ...
=======         double[] p1 = ...
                double[] p2 = ...
>>>>>>> origin/foo
```

How do I get rid of these, without having to edit each one, always choosing `HEAD`?

Merging and some stupid commands have left me without a trace of my original HEAD, but fortunately git reflog helped me to find the position before the merge.

Comment: No files need merging. Please read the question again.

Comment: I answered BEFORE you make edits and i suggest you to re-read your question again `...the only version of a big file is from trying to merge...`

Comment: I don't know what you want to accomplish, the result you quoted is a merge conflict result and caused by space changes, you can either choose to use ours strategy or ignore-space-changes while merge or rebase whatever.

Comment: If you lost you HEAD, try `git reflog`, it will show the HEAD reference history, I believe you can get you previous HEAD back there if you are not clean the reflog history. After you find the previous HEAD commit hash, just do a `git reset --hard COMMIT_HASH`(You need to read the man page about this command before runnint it, it is a little dangerous though, if not doing right, you may lose you current HEAD).

Comment: I needed reflog to find the state before the merge. Then it all worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to choose HEAD always, then you are looking for a `merge strategy` called `ours`.

Do `git merge -s ours <branch-to-merge>`

Quoting git help on merge:

> MERGE STRATEGIES
>          The merge mechanism (git-merge and git-pull commands) allows the backend merge strategies to be chosen with -s option. Some
>          strategies can also take their own options, which can be passed by giving -X arguments to git-merge and/or git-pull.

```
   recursive
       This can only resolve two heads using a 3-way merge algorithm. When there is more than one common ancestor that can be used
       for 3-way merge, it creates a merged tree of the common ancestors and uses that as the reference tree for the 3-way merge.
       This has been reported to result in fewer merge conflicts without causing mis-merges by tests done on actual merge commits
       taken from Linux 2.6 kernel development history. Additionally this can detect and handle merges involving renames. This is
       the default merge strategy when pulling or merging one branch.

       The recursive strategy can take the following options:

       ours
           This option forces conflicting hunks to be auto-resolved cleanly by favoring our version. Changes from the other tree
           that do not conflict with our side are reflected to the merge result.

           This should not be confused with the ours merge strategy, which does not even look at what the other tree contains at
           all. It discards everything the other tree did, declaring our history contains all that happened in it.

       theirs
           This is opposite of ours.

   ours
       This resolves any number of heads, but the resulting tree of the merge is always that of the current branch head,
       effectively ignoring all changes from all other branches. It is meant to be used to supersede old development history of
       side branches. Note that this is different from the -Xours option to the recursive merge strategy.
```

These are some of the strategies listed.
Use `git help merge` to look for more of them.

Comment: You can not be left with these lines in your files unless you tried merging. And you did not merge correctly if you are left with these things. I suggest you rollback the merge and do it again with `ours` merge strategy (according to what you mentioned in the question). Otherwise, you have to edit files manually, and it would be prone to errors.

Comment: I needed reflog to find the state before the merge. Then it all worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore space changes while merging by passing `-X ignore-space-change` to the command line, this also works on `git rebase`.